# What is the best way to define a generic Action type in typescript with variable number of arguments and argument types?

Tags: typescript

Typescript raises a duplicate type error for this:

```
export type Action<T> = (arg:T) => void
export type Action<T1,T2> = (arg1:T1, arg2:T2) => void
```

What is the best way to define a generic Action type (similar to that existing in .net) that allows variable number of arguments, each having a different type?

The best I can find is

```
export type Action1<T> = (arg:T) => void
export type Action2<T1,T2> = (arg1:T1, arg2:T2) => void
```

Comment: Might want to search for variadic tuple types

Comment: I know variadic tuple types but would not know how to utilize them here.

Answer (score 2):

I've often seen such a type represented with a single type parameter (that is an array) instead of multiple type parameters.

Like this:

```js
type Action<TArgs extends Array<any>> = (...args: TArgs) => void;

function f(a: string, b: number) {
  // ...
}

const a: Action<[string, number]> = f;
```

But it's also not uncommon to just write the type explicitly:

```
const b: (s: string, n: number) => void = f;
```

instead of `Action<[string, number]>`.

Comment: not perfect but interesting. actually that are variadic tuple types as arguments as @roberto-zvjerkovi mentioned.